# How to customize the front end of emacs' company package

Tags: linux, emacs, autocomplete

The default front of company seems too simple for me. It just shows nothing but the completion candidates.

Someone's company, however, looks really cool that it not only shows the completion candidates, but also shows the relevant informations about the current candidate.

After googling, I hardly find any useful informations about how to customize company's front end.

I want the company to show 1) the prototype of the current candidate 2) the file path which this candidate belongs to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The relevant information about completion candidates can only be provided by libraries of that specific language.

In your case, for cpp, there is a package [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) which provides good editing experience for C/C++ languages.

Since you want it with integrate with company mode, you can use [company-iron](https://github.com/Sarcasm/company-irony) which provides a company-mode asynchronous completion backend.

You can install it from melpa

```
M-x package-install RET company-irony RET
```

and add this to your config

```
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-irony))
```

Here is a screenshot of it
[image]